# Custom User.Identity to add property

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, iidentity

I customize `RoleProvider` and `MembershipProvider` classes

I would like to add one more property in my `@User.Identity`, as do so?

**example:**

`@User.Identity.About` => .About not exist yet

I thought I'd customize `IIdentity` but do not know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your own classes that implement IIdentity and IPrincipal. Then assign them in your global.asax in OnPostAuthenticate.

Comment: `Application_PostAuthenticate(object sender, EventArgs e)`
or  `Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)` what's the difference??

Comment: PostAuthenticate is invoked *after* the membershipprovider has authenticated the request. It's therefore the proper place to add your custom identity

Comment: @jgauffin - Could you please share sample code or link? I have a same problem but I couldn't solve it.

Answer (score -1):

Just create a wrapper and override `Page.User`.